# Requesting help converting DB2 sql to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

Looking for a little help converting a query from DB2 to Oracle. I'm using an existing SQL query to add to a new report, but that report query has been written in DB2 SQL. I am trying to convert it to Oracle, and having issues with how the dates are setup.

```
  trunc_timestamp(CASE ......

        ELSE ((
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                    TRFRDATE IS NULL OR
                    TRFRTIME IS NULL 
                    THEN
                        NULL
                ELSE timestamp(substr(char(TRFRDATE), 1, 4) || '-' || 
                substr(char(TRFRDATE), 5, 2) || '-' || substr(char(TRFRDATE), 7, 2)
                || '-' || substr(digits(TRFRTIME), 1, 2) || '.' || 
                substr(digits(TRFRTIME), 3, 2) || '.' || substr(digits(TRFRTIME), 5, 2)
                || '.000000')
                
            END) + (-1) DAY)
    END, 'dd') AS "NewOrderDate",
```

As you can see above, I have a case statement that will be converted to a timestamp, the difficult part is the last part, where after calculating the timestamp, I need to subtract -1 day, and that's where I keep falling into one error or the other.

Just to be clear, the ELSE part of the above query is just concatenating the date and time and converting to timestamp. Any help figuring this out would be great.

EDIT: My query now is this, and im getting the following error:  **hour must be between 1 and 12**

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                    CARRSERV IN ('1DYT','1PRT','SATN')
                    THEN 1
                WHEN 
                    CARRSERV IN ('2DYT','SAT2')
                    THEN 2
                ELSE 3
            END = 1 AND
            TO_CHAR(
                CASE 
                  WHEN TFRDATE IS NULL OR TFRTIME IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(substr(TFRDATE, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(TFRDATE, 4, 3) || '-' || 
                      substr(TFRDATE, 8, 2) || ' ' || substr(TFRTIME, 1, 2) || '.' || 
                      substr(TFRTIME, 3, 2) || '.' || substr(TFRTIME, 5, 2))
                  END,'hh24:mi:ss') > TO_CHAR('17:00:00','hh24:mi:ss')
            THEN
                CASE 
                  WHEN TFRDATE IS NULL OR TFRTIME IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(substr(TFRDATE, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(TFRDATE, 4, 3) || '-' || 
                      substr(TFRDATE, 8, 2) || ' ' || substr(TFRTIME, 1, 2) || '.' || 
                      substr(TFRTIME, 3, 2) || '.' || substr(TFRTIME, 5, 2))
                  END
            END AS NEW_DATE from table
```

Comment: Please, provide sample input and output data to match them. Basically, you may convert date to timestamp with simple `cast`. And [date arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) in Oracle as simple as `my_timestamp_field - 1` or more verbose `my_timestamp_field - interval '1' day`

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have a sample output. I've requested that from the team but it might be a few days before I get that. I don't have access to the DB2 server myself therefore am unable to run the query. The oracle output I cannot provide either because I cannot get the query to run as of right now.

Comment: I tried the - interval '1' day but I kept getting this error: "The data types of the operands are not valid for datetime/interval arithmetic"

Comment: As long as Oracle does not have `time` datatype, what is the datatype of `TRFRTIME`?

Comment: tfrtime is string, example: 221139

Comment: _"tfrtime is string,"_   If you are converting the query to Oracle, then it would be assumed that the database is also being converted. In which case, you should take the opportunity to "correct" the data types.  tfrtime should either be a DATE or a TIMESTAMP, not a string.  In oracle a DATE is actually date and time, to the second.  TIMESTAMP is date and time, to the nano-second, and with possible variants to handle time zones.

Comment: yeah, I wish that was how the data is, but that's not currently how the data lies. I am an analyst, so I can only read data, create views, I cannot correct the data types in the database. The data lies in DB2 and in oracle, same data, two different places. So I am just trying my best to convert the query to oracle sql syntax to get it to work.

Comment: would you have any idea why I would be receiving this error: "hour must be between 1 and 12" ? I gave the hour the correct 24hr formatting yet I'm getting this error. If you see the second set of code in my post^ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right you're truncating any hour/minute/second/... portion anyway so just ignore it from the beginning.

You can simply use `to_date()` to convert a string into a `date`:

```
...
to_date(trfrdate, 'YYYYMMDD') - 1 AS "NewOrderDate"
...
```

But you should really consider to use appropriate data types and strings types aren't appropriate for date/times, date/time types are. You could for example have one `date` column instead of `trfrdate` and `trfrtime`.

And it's a `CASE` **expression** you have there, not a statement. SQL knows no control flow statements at all.

Comment: Thanks for that. So i re-wrote the query converting the date and time into timestamps, within the Case expression. I edited the post to show the query and now i'm getting another error. Please take a look.